# How to define secret once on Container Apps Environment, use in multiple Container Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I am looking for a way how to define a secret once in the Container Apps Environment, so that all apps that run inside it can reference it, without having to define it in each app individually. Specifically I am looking for ways to define docker container registry passwords only once in the CAE.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible today. Each application defines its own secrets.